# In Angular Standalone Components check imports array for unused imports

Tags: angular

Is there a compiler/ linter option to check missing/unused imports in an Angular standalone component?

I was wondering recently why my component is not working, besides the compilation was "all right".
Reason: I forgot to import the NgFor in the imports array.

[image]

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you should import the `CommonModule`, not NgFor

Comment: Thanks for the hint.
Still i am searching for some kind of linter that should tell me this.
Have you any idea?

Comment: the most closer I found in the officials docs are the [Frequently-used modules](https://angular.io/guide/frequent-ngmodules)

Comment: I'm looking for the same thing. The conversion to stand-alone components mined my html files for things to import and added them automatically to all my components. By the way, they added NgFor and not the entire CommonModule so I disagree with your assertion that @FlorianUhlmann use that here (or rather I guess the authors of Angular disagree with you :)). But now whenever I add or subtract components from my html I have to update this list manually. I **know** code exists to do it (at least add) automatically so how to access that code.  :)

Comment: Ah, there's a request for this https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/46766